# How to detect Game Center Authentication popup

Tags: ios4, game-center

I've implemented the Game Center into my game. However, one thing bothers me which is how to detect when the Game Center launches the popup to sign in. If the user is quick with their fingers and the network is a bit slow, they are able to start a game before the popup starts, which is fine, but I want to pause the game while they sign in. I thought that the `UIApplicationDelegate` method `- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application` would be called, but this is not the case.

Is there a way to detect this and thus letting me pause the game while the user attends to the popup?

Answer (score 2):

Remember that you have to implement the two following methods in order to get notified in case of changes.

Here below is my simple version..So basically you cannot start a network game, or view the ladder before being identified as the button were hidden :)

```
- (void) registerForAuthenticationNotification
{

    NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
    [nc addObserver: self
           selector:@selector(authenticationChanged)
               name:GKPlayerAuthenticationDidChangeNotificationName
             object:nil];
}
- (void) authenticationChanged
{
    if ([GKLocalPlayer localPlayer].isAuthenticated)
 {
  [networkGame setHidden:NO];
  [ladder setHidden:NO];
 }
 else
 {
  [networkGame setHidden:YES];
  [ladder setHidden:YES];
 }
}
```

Comment: I know how to find out when the authentication has changed. But I want to pause the game while the popup is being displayed so the user can enter their login details. This happens before the authentication has changed.

Answer (score 0):

From http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/14921

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationWindowDidResignActive:) name:UIWindowDidResignKeyNotification object:nil];

-(void)applicationWindowDidResignActive
{
  [[Gamemanager sharedManager] pause];

}